# Restplus API Application object is not callable?

Tags: python, rest, flask, gunicorn, flask-restplus

I'm trying to run a Restplus flask API using unicorn but i keep getting this error:

```
Application object must be callable.
```

I'm using sqlalchemy for the databse conection and models. this is my apy.py main file:

```
from apis import api
from database import db
import os

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')

application.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(application)

api.init_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 application.run(debug=True)
```

An this is how i define the **init**.py of the folder with the enpoints so i can get them organiced:

```
from flask_restplus import Api

from .status import api as status
from .cats import api as cats

api = Api(
    title='TEST API',
    version='1.0',
    description='A description',
)

api.add_namespace(status)
api.add_namespace(cats)
```

Im using dockers, and this is how I run gunicorn:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:9000", "api:api"]
```

In host I get the same error. Runing the code with just python works fine. Do I need a wsig file? If so, how should I define it?

Update:

I tried running it on Windows 10 using waitress, and Ii got this error when I tried to connect ot it:

```
Serving on http://MR:9000
ERROR:waitress:Exception while serving /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\waitress\channel.py", line 356, in service
    task.service()
  File "c:\users\mr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 172, in service
    self.execute()
  File "c:\users\mr\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\waitress\task.py", line 440, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Api' object is not callable
```

So the error is when I try to connect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that in your call to `gunicorn` viz.

`CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:9000", "api:api"]`

what you are currently asking `gunicorn` is to look at the module `api` and check for a callable named `api` in it. Correct it to the following

`CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:9000", "apy:application"]`

Sources:

1. http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn